# Before Databinder.Eval

Tags: data-binding, eval

..there used to be another method of binding items to data containers in ASP.Net using 'ItemBinder' property maybe but nothing on google refreshes my memory.

Typically,  I would have a string array which when bound to say my DataGrid should show the array's values. This is an alternative method to DataBinder.Eval().

Thanks

Comment: It would achieve the same as just using <%#Container.DataItem %> in the scenario above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the databinder.eval to bind a result.

You can just put in something like this:

`<%# (string)Container.DataItem %>'

Assuming you want the output of the array to be in a string, and assuming it's not already a string.